# Why did Medusa just leave Auran?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, inhumans-2017

After getting into a fight with Auran, Medusa

> stabs her and leaves her for dead.

Why did she just leave her lying there? Was she unaware of the regenerative power of her own guard? Did she just not care?

Comment: People don't necessarily make the best decisions when under stress.

Answer (score 1):

Medusa was trying to locate her husband, Black Bolt. 
She is surely aware of Auran's regenerative power, simply because she wasn't surprised to see Auran again, alive.

Medusa defended herself, chased away the threat that was following her and continued her quest of finding Black Bolt.